# unknown column in field list error after column name change

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I keep getting this error when I run my C# service using entity framework accessing a table that has the "Notify" column:

```
Unknown column 'Extent1.Notify' in 'field list
```

the column was named 'fetch' before. I have RENAMED it both in the database and in the code first object from 'fetch' to'notify' only. the same operation has worked with the same code but with a different database. comparing the databases shows no differences.  the error happens while rows are fetched, the column/field is not accessed explicitly. 
what could it be? is it some cache I should clear?

the full error:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
  <s:Fault>
     <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
     <faultstring xml:lang="de-DE">An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
           <InnerException>
              <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
              <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
              <Message>Unknown column 'Extent1.Notify' in 'field list'</Message>
              <StackTrace>bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp; insertedId)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp; insertedId)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.&lt;Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)</StackTrace>
              <Type>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException</Type>
           </InnerException>
           <Message>An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.</Message>
           <StackTrace><![CDATA[bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)
   bei System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.DataOwner_CEB42FCAF876F5652D9C5F2E8892BF0622E3A8A320222EA9E392E00E8F3C36D7.get_Years()
   bei VaStSystem.VaStCentral.GetDataOwnerElement(DataOwner owner, String email)
   bei VaStSystem.VaStCentral.HoleDatenInhaberInfo(String steuerId)
   bei VaStAbrufServiceApplication.VaStBelegAbrufService.HoleDatenInhaberInfo(String ecomUser, String ecomPwd, String steuerId)
   bei SyncInvokeHoleDatenInhaberInfo(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)]]></StackTrace>
           <Type>System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException</Type>
        </ExceptionDetail>
     </detail>
  </s:Fault>
```

Comment: Have you created(and run) a CodeFirst Migration?

Comment: no not really. is it necessary everywhere, even on production systems?

Comment: Yes,you need to update your db.search on Google or SO, you will find  ways to do that

Comment: db.search on google? in fact the update fails. what I did was recreating the db using structure from the db where it works and previous data and it still doesn't work.

Comment: it works with another mysql db that is EXACTLY THE SAME. I do not understand life anymore.